# Using slash in window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, hash

If I change the hash like so: `window.location.hash = "main/0/sub/1/na/false";`.
The address in the browser changes to `http://mysite.com/#main/0/sub/1/na/false`.
Page's onhashchange function fires and everything works like it is supposed to.

However, in Firebug I can see that I'm also sending a request to: `http://mysite.com/main/0/sub/1/na/false` ... URL without hash, which results in a silent 404 in the console.

When I debug I find that it happens at the `window.location.hash` point.

But, if I change the hash like so: `window.location.hash = "main=0&sub=1&na=false";` no additional request is sent.

Why is the additional request being sent in the first example?

**UPDATE:**
I noticed it sends the request after `window.location.hash` and before (during?) `$(window).bind('hashchange')`. Example if I have ...

```
window.location.hash = 'main/0/sub/1/na/false'; // Breakpoint 1 in Firebug

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // Breakpoint 2 in Firebug
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

When it stops at breakpoint 1, no request is sent. When it stops at breakpoint 2, the request is already sent.

I can see in Apache Tomcat that the request is being sent, too.

I'll add that I have jQuery and jQuery Mobile plugged in.

**UPDATE 2:**
Removing jQuery Mobile resolves the problem. However, I need it :/

**UPDATE 3**

If anyone is interested:
With jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/pioSko/hz5PU/3/

Without jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/pioSko/hz5PU/4/

Open Firebug or other debugging app and test the links.

Comment: Do the requests actually hit your server? Which version of Firebug, Firefox? I don’t see it on a really old one here, nor on a fresh Chrome, so I guess this might be a bug somewhere.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with FF 12.0 and 13.0.1. Tried `window.location.hash = "main/0/sub/1/na/false";` in Firebug console on a random page, no network requests observed.

Comment: I've created a dummy site and in it I cannot reproduce this error. Therefore, it's got to be deeper in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). I think that's intended behavior for that script, as it's designed to make URLs pretty (non-hashy) while also not reloading the page.

Comment: looks like I have hit the same problem. This issue is still open in the History.js project, see https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/301. How did you workaround-ed it? Through some History.js alternative?

Comment: Honestly struggling to remember what I was doing in December 2012, sorry. (Been using Angular ui.router for similar functionality in some more recent projects and it's been working great! Though that's obviously an Angular-specific solution.)

Comment: I have workarounded the problem by not using History.js or anything similar at all. I'm using just ```window.location.hash``` read/write and the ```window.onhashchange``` event. It is enough for my needs. The slash rewriting problem was caused by History.js (which has 168 open issues) as your answer indicates. I've have also considered [devote/HTML5-history-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) as usable alternative (alive and only 13 open issues)

Answer (score -4):

I'm going to wager a guess here. I'm pretty sure that using slashes after a hash is an invalid URL and firefox is probably trying to compensate for that by removing the hash to make is a valid URL.

Comment: Slashes after a hash are perfectly valid and normal.